Defining topological properties of functions without homeomorphisms
I started writing this thinking it was going to be more vague, but I ended up kind of half-attempting to answer my own question in the process and now my main question is whether or not my half-attempt is in the right direction.
What properties of functions are "topological"?
In looking up what it means for a property of a function to qualify as being "topological", I came across this math education paper by Hazzan (1996).
It first explains topological properties of sets in a rudimentary way based on an old topology book by Chinn & Steenrod, rather than in terms of invariance under homeomorphisms (as is what seems to be the usual definition):

A property of a set $X$ is called a topological property "if it is equivalent to a property whose definition uses only the notion of open set of $X$ and the standard concepts of set theory (element, subset, complement, union, intersection, finite, infinite, etc)" [Chinn and Steenrod, 1966, p 53].

It then goes on to describe topological properties of functions, also based on Chinn & Steenrod:

For a property of a function to be topological, it should be equivalent to a property "whose definition uses only the notions: open sets of $X$ and $Y$ [the domain and the range], images and inverse images, and the standard concepts of set theory" [Chinn and Steenrod, 1966, p. 57].

I'm a physics guy and not a math guy, but I know enough to sense that these definitions seem weak, because technically every definition involving sets is built on the above "standard concepts" of set theory, and of course, the use of "etc" instead of a proper definition is sketchy on Chinn & Steenrod's part. That being said, characterizations like this are attractive because searching for homeomorphisms between topological spaces to figure out/prove whether or not a property is topological is not something you would necessarily want to do if you're not a mathematician. There seems to be a similar sentiment with this question.
Attempt at Resolution
I looked at a copy of Chinn & Steenrod, and below their definition of topological property for a set, they say:

Briefly, a topological property of $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is one which is expressible
as a property of the family of open sets of $X$.

This is actually a little more enlightening, and led me down the rabbit hole of mathematical structures. To the best of my knowledge, the family of open sets of $X$ is simply the (chosen) topology $\tau_X$, which is a structure on $X$. It sounds like they're basically trying to say that some property $P$ of $X$ (or rather, $\tau_X$, since different topologies may be chosen) is a topological property if it is only dependent on $\tau_X$, and no other structure we might impose on $X$.
This leads me to try the following definition for sets:

Let $X$ be a set equipped with a set of structures $S_X$ which includes a topology $\tau_X \in S_X$. A property $P(X,S_X)$ is a topological property of $X$ with respect to $\tau_X$ if $P(X,S_X) = P(X,\tau_X)$.

... and the corresponding definition for functions:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, each equipped with a set of structures $S_X$ and $S_Y$ respectively, both of which include topologies $\tau_X \in S_X$ and $\tau_Y \in S_Y$. Given a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, a property $P(f)$ is a topological property of $f$ with respect to $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$ if $P(f,S_X,S_Y) = P(f,\tau_X,\tau_Y)$.

I don't have the time to try and prove that this is equivalent to invariance under homeomorphisms (wouldn't know where to start), but this is in some sense more satisfactory, because for example, I can easily show that the minima and maxima of a function are not topological properties, because the notions of minima and maxima require an order structure. On the other hand, it's easy to show that the property of being a constant function is a topological property (as is claimed in Chinn & Steenrod) because it requires only saying that $f(x) = c$ for all $x \in X$, which requires no structure at all (other than equality, which I guess is a structure of the underlying logic), i.e. we have $P(f,S_X,S_Y) = P(f,\tau_X,\tau_Y) = P(f)$.
My question
Is this a good resolution? Am I moving in the right direction here?

What makes you think your definition is invariant under homeomorphism? The property $0 \in X$ is satisfied by the singleton space ${0}$ but not by the homeomorphic space ${1}$, yet it seems to fall under your definition (which, by the way, is a rather long-winded way of spelling "a property of a topological space").

Actually, your definitions don't really make any sense, so maybe we should start there. What is the type of $P$ supposed to be? You write $P(f)$, then $P(f, S_X, S_Y)$, then $P(f, \tau_X, \tau_Y)$...

You shouldn't assume a high degree of formalized rigor in this statement that is given in Chinn/Steenrod's book, as that book was written as enrichment reading for strong U.S. high school students, not for rigorous study by upper level undergraduates or graduate students (although for accessible expository reading, such students would probably gain a lot from this book). Probably best to interpret the statement as a useful "rule of thumb", and not try to use it as the basis for a framework for rigorously proving topological spaces are homeomorphic.

@NaïmFavier I didn't necessarily think it was an equivalent definition; I'm taking a naive stab at it and it took me a long time just to get to that point. That being said, I see your point, and yeah I guess I'd have to go back to the drawing board. Surely you see my intent though?

@NaïmFavier With regards to my $P$ notation, I'm trying to say that you're describing a property of $X$ (or $f:X\rightarrow Y$) that potentially involves context regarding structures imposed on it (think of P as a logical statement that involves/"is a function of" $X$ and its structures $S_X$). I'm going off my example that the minima and maxima of a function aren't topological properties (at least that's what I've come to gather)... I want to understand why in a way that doesn't involve homeomorphisms, if possible.

I think you just need to start thinking with types. In full generality, given sets $X, Y$, a partial order $\leq$ on $Y$ and a function $f : X \to Y$, being the maximum of $f$ is a property of an element of $Y$ that determines it uniquely. Now if you don't have an order on $Y$, you can't talk about the maximum of $f$; the notion does not apply there, it isn't well-typed. Does that clear your confusion?

@NaïmFavier No, because I have no knowledge/concept of types -- my explorations so far just haven't gotten me there. When you say well-typed I don't know what you're talking about. I'm curious to know though :)

Since topologies are properties of sets it typically makes sense to replace a function $f(x)$ with its graph $\Gamma = (x,f(x))$ since it's a set. Now questions of a functions continuity become about connectedness.
